# Its posible to pass some file path into jquery or javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass some files path into a **JavaScript** or **Jquery** function, so this can display those files (HTML files) into a div when clicking an `a` tag.

its possible?

something like this:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function loadcontent(pathfile){
      $('#content').load("pathfile");
    });
  </script>
```

The div:

```
<div id="content">
  HTML FILE HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Browser's Javascript does not have direct access to files, no.

Comment: @Keith the files are hosted on a server, not even like that?

Comment: @josealexanderpascualrosa  You maybe need to update your question -> `I want to pass some file path`  ,  maybe say HTTP URL instead, as that's possible, but a file path is not.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the path. If it's a local path (eg. `file://C:/foo.txt`) then no, you cannot do this for security reasons.

If it's a relative path to a public resource held on your own server (eg. `/folder/file.html`) then yes, this is possible. In your case you would just need to fix your syntax to create a valid function and provide the argument to `load()`:

```
jQuery($ => {
  loadContent('/path-to-your/file.html');
});

function loadContent(path) {
  $('#content').load(path);
}
```